# How update my objects in a document's array in mongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, object

i have the following collection, I have one question about:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("123456789"),
    "user_id" : 123456,
    "total" : 100,
    "items" : [
            {
                    "item_name" : "my_item_one",
                    "price" : 30
            },
            {
                    "item_name" : "my_item_two",
                    "price" : 30
            },
            {
                    "item_name" : "my_item_three",
                    "price" : 30
            }
    ]
}
```

how i can update all price concurrently, (price=50 in all objects)
thanks for help

Comment: Which language or connector are you using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [positional all operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/upcoming/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) to update all elements in the array

```
db.collectionName.update(
   { },
   { $set: { "items.$[].price" : 50 } },
   { multi: true }
)
```